# bootstrap 3rd level menu not working on click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have 3 level menu structure

Main Menu
   Menu 1
     Menu 1 -1

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="tittle">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Main Menu </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu 1</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">Menu 1 -1</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" >Menu 1 -2</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" >Menu 1 -3</li>
                </ul>
            </li><li class="dropdown"><a  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu 2</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">Menu 2 -1</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" >Menu 2 -2</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" >Menu 2 -3</li>
                </ul>
            </li><li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu 3</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">Menu 3 -1</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" >Menu 3 -2</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" >Menu 3 -3</li>
                </ul>
            </li><li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu 4</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">Menu 4 -1</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" >Menu 4 -2</li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu" >Menu 4 -3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

this is my code structure

if i click Main menu it will show Menu 1, Menu 2, Menu 3

then if i click Menu 1 it will not show Menu 1 -1, Menu 1 -2, Menu 1 -3

if i click Menu 1 this **aria-expanded="false"** changed into false in Main Menu

How to fix this? or can you please suggest any other way

Comment: By third level you mean "Menu 1-1"? 
Shouldnt there be an <a> tag round the menu text?

Comment: Sorry I'm not getting

Answer (score 1):

Simplified version, but it should get you going.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainmenu" class="row">
  <div class="list-group panel">
    <a href="#menu1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#mainmenu">Menu <span class="menu-ico-collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
    <div class="collapse pos-absolute" id="menu1">
      <a href="#submenu1" class="list-group-item sub-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#submenu1">Menu 1 <span class=" menu-ico-collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
      <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="submenu1">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#submenu1">Menu Menu 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#submenu1">Menu Menu 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#submenu1">Menu Menu 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#submenu1">Menu Menu 4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```